# Series Equaling Euler–Mascheroni Constant

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Is there a known series equaling the Euler–Mascheroni Constant? And if there is this, wouldn't that imply that the Harmonic series plus this new series equal a series that is exactly $\ln(x)$? I have been trying to derive the series  using the infinite product representation of $\ln(x)$ and manipulate it to get a series which I then could subtract that from the Harmonics to get my series, but it lead no where.

Comment: Note that $\sum_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}}  \ne \ln n + \gamma$. You can find several representations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant). For series expansions of $\ln$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Power_series).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is; e.g.
$$\gamma = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{k} - \log \left(1 + \frac{1}{k}\right)\right). \tag{1}$$

But this is just a rephrasing of the definition $$\gamma = \lim_{n \to \infty} H_n - \log n, \tag{*}$$ the proof of which I leave as an exercise.  So you gain nothing by using this particular series representation.

There are other series though:

$$\gamma = \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\zeta(n)}{n} \tag{2}$$ as well as
$$\gamma = 1 - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k = 2^{n-1}}^{2^n - 1} \frac{n}{(2k+1)(2k+2)}. \tag{3}$$

Reference:  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html

Comment: The first series converges quicker than the limit definition, so in a way you do gain something.